# Python Pandas - Moving rows around

Tags: python, pandas

I am sure this is probably simple, but I am not sure how to do it.

I have a data frame (pivot table) with 4 rows, lets call them A, B, C, D.

Now, I don't want them in alphabetical order, but I want them as B, C, A, D going down.

How do I move rows around? Obviously in Excel I would just cut and paste it. Can I do it in Python?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Use* [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)**
*`loc` allows you to pass an indexer that refers to the rows(columns) with the respective labels*

```
df.loc[['B', 'C', 'A', 'D']]
```

---

***`numpy`***
*nuclear overkill... but faster*

```
i = df.index.values
v = df.values
a = i.argsort()
u = np.empty_like(a)
r = np.arange(a.size)
u[a] = r
n = list('BCAD')
pd.DataFrame(v[i[a].searchsorted(n)[u]], n, df.columns)
```

---

***Timing***
*test data*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=range(4)), list('ABCD'))
```

*results*

```
%timeit df.loc[list('BCAD')]
1000 loops, best of 3: 361 µs per loop

%%timeit
i = df.index.values
v = df.values
a = i.argsort()
u = np.empty_like(a)
r = np.arange(a.size)
u[a] = r
n = list('BCAD')
pd.DataFrame(v[i[a].searchsorted(n)[u]], n, df.columns)
10000 loops, best of 3: 135 µs per loop
```

Comment: Ahhh, thank you ever so much. I will mark your answer as correct as soon as it will allow me. Thank you for being so fast :)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to enter extra detail (for myself and others who may find this page), very helpful for my learning.

Comment: @ScoutEU Your appreciation is appreciated :-) I also enjoy doing this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Since the straightforward answer has been given already, here is an alternative: use a [categorical index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#categorical-index).

```
cats = pd.Categorical(list('ABCD'), categories=['B','C','A','D'])
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4], index=cats)
df.sort_index()
```

Comment: I was going to mention this too.  Glad you did.